# Google API Memory Exhaust Error

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, adsense

I am using **laravel 5.1**

and continously getting memory exhausting error in **Google Adsense API**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 38 bytes) in \vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php on line 240
```

already incread memory limit to 1GB

```
  ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

TRIED:

set it again with bigger

```
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
```

and got this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1929641984) (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in \vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php on line 240
```

Here's my code

```
private function adsense_update($account_id) 
{

  $output = ".:: Processing Adsense ::. <br />";

  if (!$account_id)
  {
    $output .= "!! PLEASE ADD YOUR ADSENSE ACCOUNT ID OR PUBLISHER ID !!<hr>";
    return $output;
  }


  $client = new \Google_Client();
  $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly');
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  $client->setAuthConfigFile(config_path().'/google_client_secrets.json');
  // $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/adserver/public/adinfo_refresh');

  if (isset($_GET['code']) && !session('access_token')) {
 $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
 $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
 session(['access_token'=>$client->getAccessToken()]); 
 AdInfoController::saveAccessToken(session("access_token"));
 $output .= "Done";
  }

  if (isset($_GET['code']))
  {
      return  \Redirect::to('refresh');
  }

      if (session('access_token')) {
        $client->setAccessToken(session('access_token'));
      } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
      }

        if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
               session(['access_token'=>$client->getAccessToken()]);
        }

        if (isset($authUrl)) {
          $output .= "<a class='login' href='" . $authUrl . "'>Google Login IN to Confirm Your Account</a><br />"; 
          } 

  $service = new \Google_Service_AdSense($client);

  // $client->setAccessToken($google_access_token);

  if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

    $optParams = array(
      'metric' => 'AD_REQUESTS_RPM',
    );
    try{

    $report = $service->accounts_reports->generate($account_id, 'today', 'today', $optParams);
  }catch(Exception $e)
  {
    //An Token Error Occured
   $this::deleteAccessToken();
   // Authentication Needs to Refreshed
   $this::adsense_update($account_id);
   return;
  }
    if(isset($report)) {
      $output .= "Got AdSense results<br />";
      // print_r($report);
      if (isset($report['rows']) && array_key_exists(0, $report['rows'])) {
        $rpm = $report['rows'][0][0];
      } else {
        $rpm = 0;
      }

      $output .= "AdSense RPM: ".$rpm."<br />";

      DB::table('ads')->where('id', 1)->update([
        'last_rpm' => $rpm,
        'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
      ]);

      $output .= "Updated Database with AdSense RPM<br />";
    }

  }
          $output .= "AdSense Processing Done</p><hr>";

  return $output;
}
```

**any solution for this ?** Thanks in advance

Comment: Check Your code. For example you can create object A that in constructor create object B, and that object create object A. Boom! - Memory exhausted

Comment: Nopes! was working fine before, today got this error, Working in a single instance only.

Comment: What's the actual code

Comment: Still check your code, problem exist there. Increasing memory limit don't fix anything.

Comment: code added to question! please have a look

Comment: @AliZain After what line in your code you get memory exhausted error?

Comment: @walkingRed sir, as defined above this error is logged

**PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 38 bytes) in \vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php on line 240**

Comment: and line 240 is????????

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nD3VLpuw line 240 is (21 in pastebin)